# Zero-out margin of single elements

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin

Is there any way of zeroing-out the margin of single elements? In the code snippet I've zeroed-out the margin by setting the html and body margin to 0. But actually I would like to zero-out the margin of the table only, so that its inner content and the rest of the html body content keeps the 'standard' margin.

Have a look to the screenshots I've added.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <style>
      html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
    <title>Zero-out margin of single elements</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <p>This text should've its standard margin</p>
    <table>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">This text should've its standard margin. Only the table should extend the browser width.</p>
    </td>     
    </table>
    <hr>
    <p>This hr should've its standard margin too</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Have a look at this to better understand what I mean: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Content extending/ reaching full browser width: https://jsfiddle.net/48qeuanf/1/

Content not extending/reaching full browser width (standard margin): 
https://jsfiddle.net/48qeuanf/2/

## Browser with default margin:

[image]

## Html extending default margin

[image]

## Browser with default margin (Code)]:

[image]

## Html extending default margin (Code):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
     body
{
  margin:0
}
body > *
{
  margin:3px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin : initial
  }
  td > p
  {
    margin:2px;
  }
```

The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value.
The `element > *` selector selects all the child elements of that element

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g34Ljna/)

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem. https://jsfiddle.net/48qeuanf/1/  I'll add some screenshots to get more specific about what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I've uploaded some screenshots. I hope they'll help to understand me.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check and tell if that is what you need